# Moving average aggregation MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, moving-average

I'm looking for a simple way to calculate the 90-day moving average for a given date. I have a document called Response which has the given structure:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("60e4cf6e783e125bd80f1cf5"),
 createdAt: 2021-07-06T21:47:26.282+00:00,
 value: 8
}
```

I know how to calculate the 90-day moving average for a given date, for example 2021-08-10, but what I want to achieve is an array of this type:

```
[ 
  {date: 2021-08-10, average: 6.7}, 
  {date: 2021-08-09, average: 6.8},
  {date: 2021-08-08, average: 6.5},
  ...
]
```

I've tried to calculate the moving average for a set of dates inside a loop but the performance is absolutely atrocious considering I need to calculate this for as much as to 365 differente dates.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Have a look at Mongo 5.0 new feature [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running Monog 5.0 yet, then this would be a starting point:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$data" }] },
               as: "idx",
               in: {
                  createdAt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.createdAt", "$$idx"] },
                  window: {
                     $filter: {
                        input: "$data",
                        cond: {
                           $and: [
                              { $gte: ["$$this.createdAt", { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.createdAt", "$$idx"] }] },
                              { $lt: ["$$this.createdAt", { $add: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$data.createdAt", "$$idx"] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90] }] }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  },
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               in: {
                  createdAt: "$$this.createdAt",
                  window:  "$$this.window.value",
                  average: {$avg: "$$this.window.value"}
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: This was very helpful as a first approach to actually finding a solution to my problem. Posting the definite solution I came up to as an answer in case its usefull for anybody. Very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Wernfried answer was very close to what I needed as a solution. Here is my final approach:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

{
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        data: {
          $push: "$$ROOT",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        data: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $range: [0, period],
            },
            as: "idx",
            in: {
              date: {
                $subtract: [
                  moment().toDate(),
                  { $multiply: [1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, "$$idx"] },
                ],
              },
              window: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$data",
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $lte: [
                          "$$this.createdAt",
                          {
                            $subtract: [
                              moment().toDate(),
                              { $multiply: [1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, "$$idx"] },
                            ],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        $gte: [
                          "$$this.createdAt",
                          {
                            $subtract: ["$date", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        data: {
          $map: {
            input: "$data",
            in: {
              date: "$$this.date",
              score: {
                $avg: "$$this.window.value",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
])
```

Where period is the amount of days I need the moving average. This will yield the following response for period = 7:

```
[
  { date: 2021-08-11T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.513605442176871 },
  { date: 2021-08-10T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.513605442176871 },
  { date: 2021-08-09T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.556818181818182 },
  { date: 2021-08-08T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.556818181818182 },
  { date: 2021-08-07T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.556818181818182 },
  { date: 2021-08-06T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.556818181818182 },
  { date: 2021-08-05T21:49:49.097Z, score: 6.497863247863248 }
]
```

Comment: `new Date(moment())` is a bit useless, simply `moment().toDate()`

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer